# asp.net ajax radeditor export to rtf

Tags: telerik

when i type text in radeditor and apply font and font style and color to the text and then export to rtf and save the file and open that file all formatting that made with text like font,font size,color is not in that file. And font is set to the times new Roman.

this thing also happens with radeditor export to rtf demo on telerik site Try

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/rtfexport/defaultcs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

**RadEditor** uses two different free libraries to provide Import to RTF and Export to RTF features.

The first one used to provide RFT to HTML importation is available in this CodeProject's article: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/RtfConverter.aspx. 
The library used for HTML to RTF exportation is available here http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/RtfConverter.aspx.
As you can see both libraries are written by different developers and they are not fully compatible with each other.

For your convenience I prepared a list of know limitations of the Import and Export features of both libraries:

RFT to HTML (Import)

bold - supported. I was able to export bold formatting from the provided by you Bold.rtf file.
italic - supported
underline - supported
foreground and background colors - supported
table elements - unsupported
images- unsupported
indentations - unsupported

HTML to RTF (export)

bold - supported.
italic - supported
underline - unsupported
foreground and background colors - unsupported
table elements - partially supported - table borders are not exported
images- unsupported
indentations - supported

The unsupported scenarios are hard for development and require more time for implementations and testing. Our development is concentrated currently on producing valid XHTML content and the import and export problems are logged with medium priority in our ToDo list. That is why we could not provide firm estimate for when the required features will be available.

Please note that good RTF import and export tools are very expensive. That is why if you are currently not satisfied with the offered by RadEditor RTF functionality, you can search in Internet for another free or paid RTF to HTML importation and HTML to RTF exportation tools and we will help you to integrate them with RadEditor.